# Emotion of Subhadra during her marriage

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, women, arjuna, subhadra

There are two questions on this site regarding the marriage between Subhadra and Arjuna:

[Arjun and Subhadra's marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40425/arjun-and-subhadras-marriage)

[Arjuna and Subhadra marriage](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/arjuna-and-subhadra-marriage)

But no question or answer deals with the emotion of Subhadra before or during the marriage. Krishna tells Arjuna the [following](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14562/661) words

> O Partha, as we do not know this girl's temper and disposition. In the
> case of Kshatriyas that are brave, a forcible abduction for purposes
> of marriage is applauded, as the learned have said.

I do not know whether Subhadra likes it or not.

Does any scripture tell explicitly about Subhadra's emotion **before or during marriage** towards Arjuna?

Note that the word marriage here refers to the wedding ritual.

Comment: Can't understand the reason behind down-vote.......

Comment: Thanks, @Rickross. These people are creating trouble. If they comment and downvote, then I can improve based on the comment. But they are downvoting to create trouble only.

Comment: @Rickross Oh! I remember our discussion, but forget about user. Now realised.

Comment: Yeah it's the same.

Comment: BTw I'm deleting my comments as its not nice for others to see them.

Comment: @Rickross okay...

Comment: during so called abduction subhadra was the chariotteer that is the reason that yadavaa army doesnt persude till end to stop get subhadra back.. as its subhadra wish to be united with arjuna.. otherwise yadava army along with balarama wanted to follow and get subhadra back and kill the abductor. they asked the opinion of krishna, krishna say this as the reason for not pursuing as nobody would marry a girl who is abducted and also went willingly.. the other chatriyas would question the integerity

Answer (score 4):

**Raksasha** marriage was practiced among **Kshtriyas**, it is kind of immoral. Lets have a look at what Raksasha marriage is as mentioned in **Manusmriti:**

> 3.33. The forcible abduction of a maiden from her home, **while she cries out and weeps, after (her kinsmen) have been slain or wounded** and (their houses) broken open, is called the Rakshasa rite.

As you can see here, the women is all **crying and weeping** but if Subhadra abduction is immoral or not is not known because in Mahabahrata it is nowhere mentioned that Subhadra was **weeping or resisting** or that it happened against her will-

> Meanwhile Subhadra, having paid her homage unto that prince of hills, Raivataka and having worshipped the deities and made the Brahmanas utter benedictions upon her, and having also walked round the hill, was coming towards Dwaravati. The son of Kunti, afflicted with the shafts of the god of desire, suddenly rushed towards that Yadava girl of faultless features and forcibly took her into his car. **Having seized that girl of sweet smiles**, that tiger among men proceeded in his car of gold towards his own city (Indraprastha). Meanwhile, the armed attendants of Subhadra, beholding her thus seized and taken away, all ran, crying towards the city of Dwaraka.

Infact **Vyasa** here addresses her as '**girl of sweet smiles**' While someone is weeping this kind of addressing is not made in Mahakavya. For example in Ramayana a hopeless,beautiful girl who was weeping after being raped by Ravana is referred as '**crushed lotus**'

Also here is a reference from **Srimad Bhagvatam** which says she also fell for him-

> (6) With his eyes wide open of happiness, he saw the wonderful girl there who enchanted heroes. Smitten he fixed his mind on her. (7) Seeing him who stole each woman's heart, **she desired him also. She fixed her heart and eyes upon him and full of desire bashfully smiling cast sidelong glances**. (8) Thinking of nothing but her, Arjuna awaited the right opportunity. With his heart trembling of the strongest desire, he could find no peace. (9) When she during an important religious festival rode away from the fortress in a chariot, the mighty warrior seized the opportunity to abduct the girl who had stolen his heart. That occurred with the consent of her parents and Kṛṣṇa.

**Srimad Bhagvatam 10.86.(1-9)**

Answer (score 0):

We are told in *Harana-Harika Parva*, the section immediately following *Subhadra-Harika Parva* which narrates the actual abduction:

> [Krishna] went Subhadra who was dressed in red silk. Partha sent her away to dress in the garments worn by a corherd girl. But the illustrious one looked beautiful even in that attire. Arriving in the best of houses, the famous and beautiful Bhadra, wife of a warrior, with copper-red eyes, paid homage to Pritha. Then with a face as radiant as the full moon,  Bhadra went quickly to pay homage to Draupadi, saying, "I am your maid." Then Krishna arose and embraced Madhava's sister and lovingly said, "Let your husband not have a rival." With a happy heart, Bhadra replied, "May it be that way, O Janemaya!" The Maharatha Pandavas were then happy in their hearts. Kunti was also extremely delighted.

Shubhadra would not have 'a face as radiant as the full moon' if she was not happy with the marriage and which this extract confirms as she answers Krishna 'with a happy heart.'

Comment: please provide a link

Comment: @hanugm: Why? I've provided the chapter which itbis in. Go look it up if you're interested.

Comment: The OP asks before or during marriage but you provided answer for after the marriage.. emotions before or during marriage can change after marriage, right?? BDW, here Krishna is Draupadi..

Comment: @MoziburUllah that's why I asked for the link.

Comment: @YDS: I know how to read and no thanks to your confusing the issue.

Comment: @hanugm: There's enough information in the text of the answer to find the extract in whatever translation of the Mahabharata you have to hand Right after the abduction scene of Subhadro and you ask for descriptions of her emotion **before** and **during** the marriage. That's the place to go to, one would think.

Comment: @YDS: FYI, 'Draupadi' is the name quoted at that point in the translation that I used. I imagine the translator decided to stick closely to the original text instead of using the same name throughout as one might do in a modern novel. That happens quite often in epics as names are of great importance.

Comment: @YDS: There's a difference between marriage and marriage ceremony. Do you know the difference?

Comment: @MoziburUllah I felt that it is not only a mathematics site. As per you, I am  asking for whole life then. Updated!

Comment: When you quote something, provide chapter and verse numbers or online links for quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

Subhadra was happy -

> "He
>  once
>   went
>   to
>   Hrishikesha in
>   Dvaravati
>   and
>  there
>   obtained
>   as
>   his
>   wife
>   Subhadra,
>   with
>   eyes
>  like
>   the
>   blue
>   lotus,
>   sweet
>   of
>   speech
>   and
>   Vasudeva’s
>   younger
>   sister.
>   **As
> Shachi with
>   the
>  great
>  Indra
>  and
>   Shri with
>   Krishna,
>   Subhadra
>   was
>   delighted
>   to
>   be
>  united
>   with
>   Pandu’s
>  son,
>   Arjuna."**

Adivansavatarana Parva, Mahabharata, BORI.