# Did parents ever force a girl to marry against her will?

Tags: marriage, women

I know several instances in the scriptures in which women marry according to their choice. In some cases, parents entirely leave to the will of the girl, and in other cases, a girl marries the loved one even though her parents are not in complete agreement. In the latter cases, girls generally wait till their parents agree. *I never came across any instance in which parents make their daughter's marriage *forcefully* against her choice.* So, it seems that Sanatana dharma always provides freedom of choice to a girl in her marriage.

Some of the instances that are in support of the above arguments are:

**#1**: [Draupadi rejecting Karna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29588/scriptural-basis-for-draupadis-decision-of-denying-karna)

> Draupadi loudly said, '**I will not select a Suta for my lord**.' Then
> Karna, laughing in vexation and casting glance at the Sun, threw aside
> the bow already drawn to a circle.

**#2**: Savitri's search for her partner based on her father's words

> And the king said, 'Daughter, the time for bestowing thee is come! Yet
> none asketh thee. **Do thou (therefore) thyself seek for a husband equal
> to thee in qualities!** That person who may be desired by thee should be
> notified to me. **Do thou choose for thy husband as thou listest.** I
> shall bestow thee with deliberation.
>
> [[Sectin 266, Pativrata-mahatmya Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03291.htm)

**#3**: Sasikala marrying Sudarśana after a debate with her parents

> Hearing these words from her daughter, the king Subāhu trusted her,
> and firmly resolved to act according to that, and to celebrate the
> marriage of Śaśikalā.
>
> [[61, Chapter 20: On the Svayamvara hall and the kings conversation there, 3,
> The Devi Bhagavata Purana - book cover
> The Devi Bhagavata Purana]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57153.html)

And there is [Suvarchala's story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52212/story-of-suvarchala-asking-for-a-blind-husband-who-can-able-to-see) in which the father agrees with his daughter and waits for her decision though he wants to marry his daughter quickly.

But, I may be unaware of some instances. Are there any such instances in scriptures where parents performed forceful marriage against the choice of the girl?

Comment: is subhadra a example?

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow No, [Subadra was happy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/emotion-of-subhadra-during-her-marriage).