# Story of Suvarchala asking for a blind husband who can able to see

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, translation-request

I read a story of Suvarchala from Mahabharata in the Telugu language. But I cannot able to find the same in [this English translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm).

The following is the storyline

> There was a viprarshi named Devala. Suvarchala is his daughter. After
> coming to young age, Suvarchala asks her father to search for a blind
> husband who can able to see. After some discussion with her daughter,
> Devala asks his disciples to search for a groom. Many Brahmins
> assembled for swayamwara. Suvarchala announced her condition. All the
> participants felt it was a nuisance and left. But afterward, after
> hearing it from others, Swethakethu came for marrying her. Suvarchala
> and Swethakethu have a Vedantic discussion. Suvarchala accepted
> Swethakethu as her husband. They spend their life peacefully and
> finally attained moksha.

In the Mahabharata I read in Telugu, this chapter is present in the Mokshadharma Parva. Although I presented it in a very concise form, it is large enough.

I want to know whether it is present in any English-translated versions of Mahabharata. Along with it, are there any other scriptures that contain the story of Suvarchala and Swethakethu?

Answer (score 1):

This story is only their in southern edition. KMG follows northern edition. This story can be found in Gita press [Mahabharata Santi Parva 220.](https://archive.org/details/LqcA_mahabharat-shanti-parva-vol-5-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n625/mode/2up?view=theater)

Comment: But I am asking for the English version.

Comment: So, it does not have any English translation yet?

Comment: @hanugm I don't know about any English translation of southern edition.

Comment: @hanugm I am trying to search the Sanskrit verses in northern edition