# Why did Arjuna marry his cousin sister Subhadra going against the Smriti?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma-shastras, arjuna, manu-smriti

Arjuna married Subhadra. Even Dharmaraja Yudhisthira did not oppose the cousin marriage. Krishna actively supported it.

However, Dharmashastras do not support cousin marriage for North Indians [Cross-cousin(mother's sister's daughter) marriage? [Please refer to questions I linked]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45007/cross-cousinmothers-sisters-daughter-marriage-please-refer-to-questions-i/48044#48044)
Why they all went against Dharmashastras?

By the way, this is not a duplicate of this question [[https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/arjuna-and-subhadra-marriage]](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14551/arjuna-and-subhadra-marriage). This question was about the story of the marriage. It has nothing to do with the Dharmic dilemma.

Comment: In Arjuna's case one thing is diff.. Kunti was adopted by Kunti Bhoj..may be some rule diff for such cases..but Krishna's son, grandson too married daughter of their maternal uncle..

Comment: @YDS Yes, the Kunti Bhoj point is a valid point in the case of Arjuna.

Comment: @YDS but Pradyumna also married daughter of Rukmini, so did Aniruddha. I think the marriage with only paternal cousin is prohibited due to gotra reason.

Comment: See [these instances](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fk1dhn9W-44C&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=why+pradyumna+married+the+daughter+of+his+maternal+uncle&source=bl&ots=pBDwLp2YKP&sig=ACfU3U3nxsjyDM6M3ahdu4LICDp7bgskFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU-de43b_yAhVZfSsKHfLVD4QQ6AF6BAgZEAM#v=onepage&q=why%20pradyumna%20married%20the%20daughter%20of%20his%20maternal%20uncle&f=false)...looks like such marriages were common in kings at least..

Comment: cos they were not blood-related cos kunti was adopted. also for gandharva vivaha of kshatriyas, maybe there are exceptions ?

Comment: Marrying one's maternal cousin is a practice unique to South Indian Hindus. All panditas hailing from South India find no objection to it but those from North India vehemently oppose it. North Indian panditas state that one shouldn't marry within the 5 generations of the maternal gotra but South Indian panditas state that since a person inherits only the paternal gotra, marrying one's maternal cousin doesn't qualify as sagotra marriage.

Answer (score 5):

Both arjuna and kruShNa belonged to puru-yadu > yayAti > soma family i.e. Lunar dynasty which was heterodox family (as one can find many controversies like soma-tAra-brihaspati issue, in musaLa parva kruShNa himself says that yadus are burden for the earth and hence need to be eliminated, etc.)

On the other hand surya > manu > ikshvaku >... family was an orthodox family and hence one cannot find such cousing marriages in that family in epics.

Comment: Interesting point

Answer (score 1):

Sri Krishna knew this marriage is not in accordance to dharma, but as omniscient he was, he knew only through Subhadra, Pandava's lineage would survive, which indeed happened, as Abhimanyu's son Parikshit was sole survivor. So, in bhagavata purana, it specifically says, that even though it was adharma, shree krishna allowed it.

-Puri Shankaracharya ji. I saw it in one of his videos.

Comment: Which video? You have to give the source to that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto my bad, the video actually doesnt say exactly that, i misunderstood. Though it may indicate it. Check the video https://youtu.be/OYh5l1URJcM

Comment: Sorry I donot have strength to watch full video and make out where exactly Puri Shankaracharya said that. As you said, he didn't exactly say that, it means your answer is mere your assumption and with no sources. Hence will be deleted.

Comment: @Rudra , Shri Krishna had taken avatar to destroy adharma and to establish dharma , why would he tolerate adharma?

Comment: @Rudra Interesting point. You said it is mentioned in Bhagavata. Can you please refer to the verse?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay as i said in the above comments, its not about subhadra and arjuna but in bhagavata, its about one of shree krishna's sons marriage to nephew of Rukmini. Check the video in the link shared above.